# Dozer mapping Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, mongodb, dozer

I use Dozer Mapper to map my objects between dao layer (MongoDB is used) and business logic layer. Actually, objects structure is identical.

**Document class *(semantically is closer to business logic layer)***

```
public class Document {
    private String id;
    private String schema;
    private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
}
```

**DocumentEntity class *(semantically is closer to dao layer)***

```
public class DocumentEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("schema")
    private String schema;

    @Field("attributes")
    private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Here's an example of `dozer-bean-mappings.xml`

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>DocumentEntity</class-a>
    <class-b>Document</class-b>
</mapping>
```

And here's the method that converts one object into another before saving it to MongoDB

```
DocumentEntity toEntity(Document document) {
    DocumentEntity entity = new DocumentEntity();
    mapper.map(document, entity);
    return entity;
}
```

As you can see one the field `attributes` is `Map<String, Object>`. Everything worked fine until I tried to map complex type "inside" `Object`. I needed to have list of objects with two fields each as value of this Map.

At the top level there's REST API that provides saving objects to MongoDB. But because of Dozer's incorrect mapping types become invalid.

**JSON input**

```
{
  "schema":"sch_1",
  "attributes": {
      "objUID": "obj_1",
      "nestedObjects": [
        {
          "objUID": "obj_1_1",
          "objSchema": "sch_1_1"
        },
        {
          "objUID": "obj_1_2",
          "objSchema": "sch_1_2"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

**And that was saved after mapping:**

```
{
  "schema":"sch_1",
  "attributes": {
      "objUID": "obj_1",
      "nestedObjects": [
          "{objUID=obj_1_1, objSchema=sch_1_1}",
          "{objUID=obj_1_2, objSchema=sch_1_2}"
      ]
  }
}
```

So, instead getting list of objects I just get list of strings.
How should I configure dozer to get correct objects mapping?

Comment: Is someone know how to resolve this problem ? I've exactly this problem right now